# Do I need to build a new connection every time when I need to transport data?

Tags: php, database

I'm new to PHP so this question may seem dumb.

When we are connecting a php application to the database, should I put all the connection code and configuration in an separate file and include this file in every php page I have? Or do I only need to put it in index.php and the connection keeps on?

Comment: You set it once, And reuse it after that. Set it in your bootstrap and make it available to wherever you need it.

Comment: Well, not all things built with PHP follow the architecture you chose. For example, PHP frameworks have lazy loading and won't invoke the DB connection unless needed. And that's the reason why people use those frameworks. As for you and your approach - well, try to come up with something on your own. Check what you need, what you can code and what seems useful and work with that.

Comment: @tlenss What do you mean "in your bootstrap"?

Comment: @OneZero the start point of your application

Comment: The connection is closed at the end of every request. So if a user comes back and asks for a different page or even the same one again, you need to make sure there is a connection available if that page requires the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Most connections in PHP are resources, and can be stored in a variable.  Whenever you need that connection, you just pass that variable to the function that needs it ( ala `$ch = curl_init; curl_exec( $ch );` ).  Access to these variables is determined by normal scope rules; If you define the variable and then include a file, the included file has access to whatever global variables the parent defined.  If the variable is a property of a class, then it is accessible so long as it is a public property.

You should also note that, as with most things PHP (except for Sessions and Persistent Connections), these resources only live during the lifecycle of the script, namely a single request.  If you want these connections to be available for every single request then you should place the code that creates them at a point where they will be created before you need them, exists in a scope that is accessible and allows you flexibility later down the road when something changes (because change is the only constant).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create persistent connections. I typically do this using PDO. I usually create a database connection class. The class is a singleton. It establishes a persistent PDO connection and stores it as a protected field. Each of my model classes extend the database connection class, thereby inheriting access to the protected connection member.